# Parsear con java usando una ruta dinámica

Tags: java

Lo que busco es saber cómo puedo parsear una ruta de una web, teniendo en cuenta que busco un atributo que coincide con el ID del producto. De tal forma que tengo por ejemplo:

```
String codigo = "00000000-0000-400c-80cf-0002435a07d7";

String fecha = doc.select("ol.RelatedTiles li.grid-18 #p+codigo");
```

Es decir, lo que quiero es que en esta expresión `#p+codigo` aparezca la suma de la letra p y el código:

```
String fecha = doc.select("ol.RelatedTiles li.grid-18 #p00000000-0000-400c-80cf-0002435a07d7");
```

¿Es posible hacer esto o tengo que buscar otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscas concatenar cadenas:

```
String fecha = doc.select("ol.RelatedTiles li.grid-18 #p"+codigo);
```

Comment: Gracias, pensaba que tenía que estar entre las comillas dobles todo.